# SBS 2k8 Backup doesn't flush Exchange-Logs

Tags: backup, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

We're using the Small Business Server Backup that comes with SBS 2008 to backup all drives to an iomega iSCSI-Target.
The Backup works fine and everything is shown as successfully backed up.

But the exchange-logs in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Mailbox\First Storage Group` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Mailbox\Second Storage Group` aren't flushed.

What could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the backup configuration, is the box to backup the Exchange Information Store checked, or are you only backing up the drives?

Comment: SBS Backup doesn't give me that option in SBS Console. I can only select the drives to backup, the backup-target and the timeplan.

Comment: That would be why - unless your backup agent is Exchange aware (that is, it knows it's backing up an Exchange database), it treats the database as a file and does not commit the logs.

Comment: But the integrated SBS 2008 Backup should be able to backup the exchange-database, shouldn't it? I mean: Microsoft ships this backup-tool with an SBS that has ALWAYS an exchange-server on board...

Comment: Right - and your exchange database is being backed up.  It's just not aware enough to commit the logs.  It is an included tool, but it's not a full featured one.

Comment: <irony>Great!</irony>...
So, what should I do to get the logs commited? Is there any recomended way to do this?

Comment: If it were me, I'd invest in Backup Exec or any one of the number of good commercial backup applications.  That being said, if you have no budget, you can enable circular logging, but it's not my preferred method of keeping log size down.  I should also point out that you don't have mailbox level backup with the Windows tool - if you need to find a deleted email, you're overwriting the ENTIRE mailstore to get it back.

Comment: Ok then... I'll discuss that with my boss. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/41081093-963e-496f-a582-86073522ee0b/) that can do what you need on Win2k8 R2, I know you are referring to SBS however not sure how many features are included for 'Window Server Backup' within SBS.

In summary:
Windows server backup->Backup schedule->Modify Backup->Custom->Add items + Advanced Settings=>Vss Settings=>VSS FULL BACKUP->Backup Time->Destination Type->Keep or Change Backup Destination->Finish [Verify that in advance option you see VSS full backup]